# Why NaN with pd.merge?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I am trying to merge two dataframes named EPB_Timber and LCI_RedEco by using the column ecoinvent_record. The columns are objects in both dataframes.

What I am trying to do is merge in one row the information of for example CLAY BRICK RER from LCI_RedEco with the information from CLAY BRICK RER from EPB_Timber. So the output must be a new dataframe with dataframe EPB_timber in it plus the info of LCI_RedEco of the same row in 'ecoinvent_record'.

This is what EPB_Timber looks like:

```
  Year_of_emission   dummy   ecoinvent record
0 1                  565     CLAY BRICK RER
1 60                 365     CEMENT MORTAR RER
```

This is what LCI_RedEco looks like

```
   CO2sum   COsum   CH4sum   ecoinvent_record
0  11.2556  5.62466 86232.5  CLAY BRICK RER
1  555      756     215662   AIR SEPERATION FACILITY RER
```

I used this line

```
LCI_EPB_Timber = pd.merge(EPB_Timber,LCI_RedEco, on ='ecoinvent_record', how='left')
```

and this is the result LCI_EPB_Timber

```
   Year_of_emission   dummy   ecoinvent_record   CO2sum   COsum   CH4sum
0  1                  565     CLAY BRICK RER     NaN      NaN        NaN
1  60                 365     CEMENT MORTAR RER  NaN      NaN        NaN
```

Why do I get NaN? Why does it not find a 'match' in the ecoinvent_record column?

I checked manually if there is a match in the excel files (from which I made the dataframes) and there is. So in both excels 'CLAY BRICK RER' exists in the ecoinvent_record column.

How can I fix it? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: please no pictures of code/data, provide **minimal** examples as **text**

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Your `EPB_Timber` has `ecoinvent record` which doesn't have that underscore `_` between the two words.

Comment: If the missing underscore was because of your typo, and if the data shown in the question is typed by you, maybe you wanna go back to your real data and check if there is additional unexpected space characters added to the end of the strings, such as `CLAY BRICK RER     `. The trailing spaces is not visible but it can cause you problem in merge.